# Paste cell content to a textbox including text formats

Tags: vba, excel

**What I want to do**

I have some formatted text in a cell. For example, in cell A1 I could have :
**aaa** ***bbb*** *ccc*

I would like to send this text, with its format, to a textbox (NOT in a userform).

The macro recorder simply copies the text and then adjusts the format as such:

```
Range("A3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("txt_1")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "aaa bbb ccc "
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 8).ParagraphFormat. _
        FirstLineIndent = 0
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 4).Font
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorDark1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0

          etc etc
```

I read about copying the cell and pasting in a textbox but nothing seems to conserve text format. Something like

```
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Feuil1.Shapes.Range(Array("txt_1"))
```

Would be great but that's apparently not how to paste into a textbox using VBA.

Comment: You can use `Selection.Value` where "aaa bbb ccc " is to get the data you want, but not necessarily the formatting. Will look into this further

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you need to do the special formatting for each character by yourself. This way you could iterate through them to set the `.Bolt` / `.Italic`.... values. Or cheat like this:

```
Sub Macro()
  Range("A3").Copy
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("txt_1")).ShapeRange(1).Select
  Application.SendKeys ("^v")
End Sub
```

While that is a dirty way to do it... it should work... at least :/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution... I used the ActiveCell value in the example, but you could use the value of A3. This sets the ActiveCell value to Textbox 1, then loops through the ActiveCell characters looking to see if they are bold or italic, then sets formatting of individual characters in Textbox 1 accordingly:

```
Sub passCharToTextbox()

    'select Textbox 1:
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Textbox 1")).Select

    'set text:
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ActiveCell.Value

    'loop through characters in original cell:
    For i = 1 To Len(ActiveCell.Value)

        'add bold/italic to the new character if necessary:
        If ActiveCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then
            Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True
        Else
            Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = False
        End If
        If ActiveCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic = True Then
            Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic = True
        Else
            Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic = False
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object library.

```
Dim x As New MSForms.DataObject
Set x = New MSForms.DataObject
Selection.Copy
x.GetFromClipboard
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("txt_1")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = x.getText(1)
```

That should maintain formatting while allowing you to paste to a user control. Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Sources: [Paste to TextBox](http://www.developerfusion.com/thread/28447/paste-from-clipboard-to-excel-textbox),
[Paste from clipboard VBA](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/paste-clipboard-contents-vba/)

Comment: DataObjects are not recognized, do you know which library I need to activate?

Comment: Sorry, was doing the VB6 way. I would try just `x.getText` if it doesn't work. Alternatively, you may need to use the Copy to Clipboard method in the second link

Comment: I upvoted because I know it could work, but it will not work in my case because I would need to search Windows32 for FM20.DLL because as of Excel 2010 and later, the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object library is not in the reference list, and I can't do that for every machine that's going to use the code I am doing.

Comment: @DavidG - I know this is an old thread, but you can avoid using the reference through late binding (by declaring x as Object instead of MSForms.DataObject and then `Set x = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")`. See http://excelmatters.com/2013/10/04/late-bound-msforms-dataobject/